# kaprekar numbers

Tags: python

```
def kaprekar_num(num):
    count = 0
    while count <= num:
        n = 1
        sqr = n ** 2
        digits = str(sqr)
        length = len(digits)
        for x in range(1, length):
            left = int("".join(digits[:x]))
            right = int("".join(digits[x:]))
            if (left + right) == n:
                print("Number: " + str(n) + ", Left: " + str(left) + " + " + " Right: " + str(right) + " = " + str(n))
                n += 1
                count += 1
            else:
                n += 1
kaprekar_num(5)
```

hello guys,
I'm new to python programming and I got a task in class to print the first 5 kaprekar numbers.
(I only have C programming background...)
I have a problem with the "for x in range..." line.. the code doesn't enter the loop and I don't know why.
the program needs to print:

```
Number: 9, Left: 8 +  Right: 1 = 9
Number: 10, Left: 10 +  Right: 0 = 10
Number: 45, Left: 20 +  Right: 25 = 45
Number: 55, Left: 30 +  Right: 25 = 55
Number: 99, Left: 98 +  Right: 1 = 99
```

I will appreciate some insights :)

Comment: Firstly, your indentation is not correct. Everything after a `def` needs to be indented so that python understands it as "inside".

Comment: @Kris its a problem here not in pycharm ^^ but ty

Comment: n=1, 1**2 = 1, len('1') = 1, `range(1,1)` doesn't mean anything

Comment: @G.Anderson I thought this is the problem at first too, but it did work in a couple of tests I tried..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How you're managing the `n` value is incorrect.  It should be set before the loop starts, then after each try, regardless of the outcome, it should increment.

```py
def kaprekar_num(num):
    count = 0
    # Start n at one, and don't reset it on each loop
    n = 1
    while count <= num:
        sqr = n ** 2
        digits = str(sqr)
        length = len(digits)
        for x in range(1, length):
            left = int("".join(digits[:x]))
            right = int("".join(digits[x:]))
            if (left + right) == n:
                print("Number: " + str(n) + ", Left: " + str(left) + " + " + " Right: " + str(right) + " = " + str(n))
                count += 1
                # This number is a Kaprekar number, so break out of the loop
                break
        # Regardless of the status of this number, try the next one
        n += 1
kaprekar_num(5)
```

And as a recommendation:  I'd highly recommend you look into stepping through the code with a debugger in the future.  If you had done so, you'd have seen that `n` is not changing fairly quickly.

Comment: thank you that fixed the problem! im looking at the changes you made to see what i did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

for loop was fine, you had some logic issue, which you haven't handled, like when n==1 and when len(sqr)==1.

```
def kaprekar_num(num):
    count = 0
    n=1
    while count <= num:
         

        sqr = n ** 2
        digits = str(sqr)
        length = len(digits)
        if sqr==1:
            print("Number: " + str(n)  + " = " + str(n))
            count+=1
            n+=1
        elif length>1:
            for x in range(1,length):
                left = int("".join(digits[:x]))
                right = int("".join(digits[x:]))
                if (left + right) == n:
                    print("Number: " + str(n) + ", Left: " + str(left) + " + " + " Right: " + str(right) + " = " + str(n))
                    n += 1
                    count += 1
                else:
                    n += 1
        else:
            n+=1
            
kaprekar_num(5)
```

Answer (score -1):

you've set the loop to repeat once i think, if you meant to put n instead of 1, i think thats the problem.

Try to set the loop to this instead

```
for x in range(n, length):
```

Comment: i apologize i'm also new try to mix this fix with the fix above me by anon coward